# Testing Camel routes with MockEndpoint

Tags: guice, apache-camel

Why does this test fails with "java.lang.AssertionError: mock://destino Received message count. Expected: <12> but was: <0>" ? I'm just trying to test if Camel can really reorder messages.

Imports:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Produce;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.guice.CamelModuleWithRouteTypes;
import org.jukito.JukitoModule;
import org.jukito.JukitoRunner;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import com.google.inject.Inject;
```

The test:

```
@RunWith(JukitoRunner.class) public class ResequenceTest {

    @Inject protected CamelContext context;
    @Produce protected ProducerTemplate template;

    public static class Module extends JukitoModule {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") protected void configureTest() {
            install(new CamelModuleWithRouteTypes(OrderingTestRouteBuilder.class));
        }
    }

    @Test public void testDozenMsgsOrderByIntegerBody() throws Exception {
        // fail();
            Integer[] input = new Integer[] {12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4};
            List<Integer> expectedOutput = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=1; i<=12; i++) {expectedOutput.add(i);};
        for (Integer i : input) {template.sendBody("mock:receptor", i);};
        MockEndpoint resultEndpoint = context.getEndpoint("mock:destino", MockEndpoint.class);
        resultEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived(expectedOutput);
        resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

}
```

The route:

```
class OrderingTestRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
        @Override public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:start")
            .to("mock:receptor")
            .resequence(body(Integer.class))
            .to("mock:destino");
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Rodolfo

Answer (score 5):

You should setup the expectations on the mock **before** you send messages into Camel. The steps is

1. setup expectations on the mocks
2. send messages
3. assert

Comment: Yes, I realized it this morning. Thanks, Claus.

Answer (score 1):

It's passing now. I changed test to:

```
@Test public void testDozenMsgsOrderByIntegerBody() throws Exception {
    // fail();
    List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4});
    List<Integer> expectedOutput = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i=1; i<=12; i++) {expectedOutput.add(i);};
    MockEndpoint resultEndpoint = context.getEndpoint("mock:result", MockEndpoint.class);
    resultEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived(expectedOutput);
    for (Integer i : input) {template.sendBody("direct:start", i);};
    resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
}
```

and the route to:

```
class OrderingTestRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("direct:start")
       .resequence(body(Integer.class))
       .to("mock:result");
    }
}
```