# java.lang.AssertionError: Issue with Camel Mock Endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, azure-blob-storage

I'm having issue with camel route mocking. It was not able to count the route messages instead its returning "0" message count. Here is my test case and route. Can someone assist me with this ?

**WatcherRouteTest.java**

```
@CamelSpringBootTest
@SpringBootTest
@MockEndpoints
@UseAdviceWith
public class RouteTest {

  @Autowired
  CamelContext camelContext;

  @Autowired
  ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

  File resultFile;

  @EndpointInject("mock:azure-storage-blob")
  MockEndpoint storageMockEndpoint;


  @Test
  void testFlow() throws Exception {

    AdviceWith.adviceWith(camelContext, "uploadFile", a ->
        a.replaceFromWith("direct:start")
    );

    storageMockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
    storageMockEndpoint.message(0)
        .header(Exchange.FILE_NAME).isEqualTo("text.csv");

    InputStream body = fetchFileFromResourcesFolderAsStream("test-files/text.csv");
    Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put(Exchange.FILE_NAME, "text.csv");
    headers.put("CamelAzureStorageBlobContainerName","abc");
    headers.put("header.CamelAzureStorageBlobSourceBlobAccountName","abcd");

    camelContext.start();
    producerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeaders("direct:start", body, headers);

    storageMockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();

    resultFile = fileCreationUtility( "text.csv");
    assertTrue(resultFile.exists());

  }
}
```

Here is my actual implementation:

```
from("direct:upload")
        .routeId("uploadFile")
        .setHeader("CamelAzureStorageBlobSourceBlobAccountName",constant(storageAccountName))
        .toD(BLOB_URL)
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"${header.CamelFileName} Uploaded to ${header.CamelAzureStorageBlobContainerName} Container Successfully")
        .end();
```

Exception Occurred:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: mock://azure-storage-blob Received message count. Expected: <1> but was: <0>
Expected :<1>
Actual   :<0>
```

Answer (score 0):

On Workaround  try with following solution

**Solution 1):** And You should setup the expectations on the `mock` before you send messages into Camel. The steps is

**1.    setup expectations on the mocks**

**2.    send messages**

**3.    assert**

**Example:**

```
@Test public void testDozenMsgsOrderByIntegerBody() throws Exception {
    // fail();
    List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4});
    List<Integer> expectedOutput = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i=1; i<=12; i++) {expectedOutput.add(i);};
    MockEndpoint resultEndpoint = context.getEndpoint("mock:result", MockEndpoint.class);
    resultEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived(expectedOutput);
    for (Integer i : input) {template.sendBody("direct:start", i);};
    resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
}

class OrderingTestRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("direct:start")
       .resequence(body(Integer.class))
       .to("mock:result");
    }
}
```

For more details refer this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556672/testing-camel-routes-with-mockendpoint):

**Solution 2)**
The `AssertionError` complains that the two object instances are not equal what is obvious because they are not the same instance.

One of them is created in your application, the other is created in your test case.

And also Error may be due to the request body in example :HTML template. Trying to assert it with a wrong HTML template it throws the `AssertionError` error

For more details refer this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63564970/i-have-an-apache-camel-test-case-which-is-failing-because-of-different-object-inz):